# Parsing data requests from google flights using google flights package

Tags: json, r, google-qpx-express-api

I'm working on interacting with the google flights api (qpx). I am using the following link and working with the following experimental package to feed in information for a request:

https://github.com/rweyant/googleflights

Below is the code I have thus far for anyone interested in replicating my results:

```
#call library and data-------------------------------------------------------------------
library(googleflights)
library(MUCflights) #to access airport codes
data("airports")

#codes for countries i'm interested in------------------------------------------

code_list = airports
#later interface for updating codes
my_destinations = matrix(c("San Juan", "Amsterdam", "Berlin", 
                           "San Diego", "Lima", "Cali", "Havana"))

my_home = matrix(c("LGA", "JFK"))

#loop extract
code_list = airports
code_bucket = NULL
for (i in my_destinations) {
  print(i)
  drop = code_list[code_list$City == i,c("City","IATA")]
  drop = as.data.frame(drop)
  print(drop)
  code_bucket = rbind(code_bucket, drop)
  code_bucket = as.data.frame(code_bucket)

}

#clean my code bucket---------------------------------------------------------------
code_bucket = na.omit(code_bucket)
code_bucket = code_bucket[code_bucket$IATA != "",]
code_bucket


#feed in codes into function---------------------------------------------------------
#each ping to QPX will combine NYC to x

#data i want
# pricing
# times

key = "(key is here)" 
set_apikey(key)
result_flights = search(my_home[1], code_bucket[2,2], "2016-11-27", "2016-11-28")
```

I've been looking through the package details to understand the functionality and noticed that the request comes back as a list as opposed to a JSON, which seems to be for the application of a "summarise_segment" function that isn't working for me. Here is the link to the function I'm referencing:

https://github.com/rweyant/googleflights/blob/master/R/unpack.R

I'm wondering if anyone has any luck or ideas for parsing out the request that returns? The resulting list is large and I'm reaching the limits of my knowledge on dealing with these structures. Any help in pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!